# what does {% random code here %} means in HTML file

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I was given an assignment and I came across this line of code in one of HTML file of problem set. What does `{% random code here %}` means in HTML, is it a comment or what? I tried google but could not find it.

one TODO looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div class="col">
<form action="/compare" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<!-- TODO -->
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So please sort it out what it is for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably some kind of templating, for example:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/

This means that the `{% random code here %}` is meant to be filled out by a webserver before returning proper HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is an object. Most likely this is part of a template that will process some code from a backend language or javascript.  Take a look at mustache which utilizes this syntax `https://mustache.github.io/`.